# Fail to invoke QML function

Tags: qt, qml

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html chapter "Invoking QML Methods", I try to invoke the bbox function within main.qml from C++.

Here is my code :

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    Item{
        anchors.fill: parent

        Plugin{
            id: osmplugin
            name: "osm"
        }

        Map {
            anchors.fill: parent
            id: map
            plugin: osmplugin;
            zoomLevel: (maximumZoomLevel - minimumZoomLevel)/2
            center {
                // The Qt Company in Oslo
                latitude: 59.9485
                longitude: 10.7686
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted:{
            console.log("zoomlevel : " + map.zoomLevel)
            console.log("Visible region : " + map.visibleRegion)
        }

        function bbox(){
            return map.visibleRegion;
        }
    }

}
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QGeoRectangle>
#include <QQmlComponent>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, "qrc:/main.qml");

    QObject *map = component.create();
    QVariant ret;

    bool ok = QMetaObject::invokeMethod( map, "bbox",  Qt::DirectConnection, Q_RETURN_ARG( QVariant, ret ) );

    if ( !ok ){
        qWarning( "Fail to call qml method" );
    }
    QGeoRectangle rect = qvariant_cast<QGeoRectangle>( ret );

    return app.exec();
}
```

I get the following error message :

"QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method QQuickWindow::bbox()"

Seems it does not find the bbox function. Could you help me to find the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well bbox() is not method of your map(c++). Just move it from Item to Window.

Comment: Correct, thanks, it works. So, if I must let this function within Item (for example) what would be the right code to have acces to that (sub)-function of Item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your item an object name:

```
Item{
    anchors.fill: parent
    objectName: "bboxObj"

    function bbox(){
        return map.visibleRegion;
    }
}
```

In C++ get your Object using the object name:

```
QObject *map = component.create();
QObject *bboxObj= map->findChild<QObject*>("bboxObj");
```

and invoke the method:

```
if (bboxObj)
    ok = QMetaObject::invokeMethod( bboxObj, "bbox",  Qt::DirectConnection,    Q_RETURN_ARG( QVariant, ret ) );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you two. One step more for me.